# how to compair two strings from xml url in Python

Tags: python, string

I need to figure out if two strings from a site are equal. If they are the same, it goes to the next string and saves it, if they are different, it saves it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time

def get_data():
    site = 'http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/rss102.xml'
    op = urlopen(site)
    rd = op.read()
    op.close()
    sp_page = soup(rd, 'xml')
    news_list = sp_page.find_all('item')
    for news in news_list:
        print(news.title.text)
        print(news.pubDate.text)
        print('-'*60)

    
while True:
    print(get_data())
    time.sleep(5)
```

Thank's

Comment: You can compare two strings with `str1 == str2` unrelated where they come from. `print(get_data())` doesn't work. `get_data` doesn't return anything

Comment: i tried this way, but doesn't worked  ` if news.title.text in news_list:
            print(news.title.text)
        return False
    else:
        news.list.append(news.list.text)
        return()`

Comment: That's strange. It works for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Du7KJVC6txc7Hhtl

Comment: I need to post only new feed in my telegram channel using telepot. I need to compare these strings, but doesn't work for me

Comment: I can't help without [mcve]. Your question is how to compare two strings and `str1 == str2` does exactly that.

Comment: I want store only the last news from xml url. If previous stored feed is the same of the new, he skip.. How can i do that? I have no idea..

Comment: Where do you store previous items?

Comment: With for i store all feeds from xml url. I want store only the first and compare with the first everytime. But my code isn't optimized for doing that...

Comment: I checked http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/rss102.xml and didn't see any duplicates. Why do you want to compare? What do you want to compare with what? The items are ordered in chronological order. You don't have to check all items. Just compare the latest timestamp.

Comment: I want to automate my telegram channel and publish the new news. So I want to prevent the same news from being published. Thank's for the patience. (I haven't configured telepot yet, but at the moment I don't care)  || Yea! Exactly, but how i can do that?

Comment: Each item has `<pubDate>Wed, 04 Nov 2020 17:17:00 +0100</pubDate>`. The items are chronologically ordered by this value. You can store the last timestamp and just compare it. You don't need to check all items.

Comment: Yea, but how can i do that? My attempt is the previous code. I want to do exactly what you say

Comment: Convert `news.pubDate.text` to a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html) and break the loop `if prevDateTime >= currDateTime`. But you have to store the previous value somewhere in a file or database.

Comment: How can i convert? And where i put the if statement? Using this? date_time_obj = datetime. strptime(date_time_str, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')

Comment: You can use [datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert a string to a datetime but `'%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'` is not the correct format. You put the if statement into the loop. But the biggest problem is still: Where do you store the last item?

Comment: I would like to send the last feed on telegram using telepot library, so I keep the feed in a variable that I clean if and only if they are different during the check

Comment: Here you can find the [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). It's something like `'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'`.

Comment: Ok, that's work now.. But now, how can i put if statement? And i need to store in two var? Where one of it i'll use for configure telepot and send feed on telegram channel, and another one for doing checks

Comment: `if prev_date_time <= datetime.strptime(news.pubDate.text, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')`

Comment: Already do. Now i need to break and store the feed, true? Thank's a lot for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items in the XML are chronologically ordered. You can store the timestamp of the latest item and process all new items.

I'm not able to test it but it should be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
import datetime

def get_data():
    global prev_date_time
    site = 'http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/rss102.xml'
    op = urlopen(site)
    rd = op.read()
    op.close()
    sp_page = soup(rd, 'xml')
    news_list = sp_page.find_all('item')
    for news in news_list:
                         
        if prev_date_time and prev_date_time >= datetime.datetime.strptime(news.pubDate.text, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'):
            break
        print(news.title.text)
        print(news.pubDate.text)
        print('-'*60)

    if news_list:
        prev_date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(news_list[0].pubDate.text, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')

prev_date_time = None 
                                                                                                    
while True:
    get_data()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thanks! He say: prev_date_time = datetime.now()
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now' .. I'm trying to fixing, but it doens't work

Comment: Solved with: from datetime import datetime , but with the while statement doesn't work. I need to remove?

Comment: I can't see output, why?

Comment: Yes, it work now. But this code print all news. Why?

Comment: @JosephMart It prints all news once and waits for new news

Comment: Nice!!!! Thank's! Now i try to configure this code with telepot, in this way i can automate my news channel. Thank's a lot!

Comment: I understood all the logic behind it, and I thank you so much!

Comment: I have an another problem with telepot. He post 3 times the same feed..

Comment: @JosephMart This new problem is unrelated to this question. You should ask a new question.